# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Incorrect integer value: in MySQL but not on Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, mariadb, amazon-rds

I'm trying to get a local version of a PHP app installed on my own server here. It's originally from an Amazon AWS instance where the database is on RDS.

This is the full error:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'databasename'.'event_budget_line'.'parent_budget_line_id'`

This is a copy of the query:

```
INSERT INTO event_budget_lines (event_budget_line_id,event_revision_id,parent_budget_line_id,account_code,description,units,internal_cost,calc_qty,quantity,client_price,markup,event_bar_id,last_update_date, last_update_by, create_date, create_by) 
VALUES ("390","1853","","7769.01","Litedeck - (33.6m)","","","14","14","","","46201",now(),71,now(),71)
```

I understand why I'm getting the error in Mysql (lots of instances that explain how to correct this), however RDS seems to handle this differently and allows fields that are Integers to work in this way as the query will work on RDS.

Is there a way to mirror this functionality in MySQL, allowing integer fields to be populated with `""` which becomes `0`?

Comment: Run this query in both instances: `SELECT @@sql_mode;` What does it report in each?

Comment: What versions of MySQL are you running on your server and RDS?

Comment: [Strict Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict) will error for incorrect data type - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GXCCJ2N4)